# strip multiline string of non ascii chars

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am trying to get a string into the shell in IDLE. It contains some non-ascii characters that I would like to remove. I can't just paste it into a multi line string, e.g.

```
u'''✔uganda
✔zambia
✔zimbabwe
and none of these…
✕afghanistan
✕armenia
✕azerbaijan'''
```

because that would give me the following error:

```
Unsupported characters in input
```

and I can't use

```
string = [raw_]input()
```

because the string is more than one line wide.

---

How can I get the string into the shell?

Comment: I have to say that downvoting without leaving a comment is counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot define a `string` like this (on your machine), then you will need to `input` it. This means that you need some code to accept a `multi-line` input and as you read each line, check that `ord()` of each character is less than `256` (i.e. it is in the `ASCII`set).

Here is said code:

```
inpt = ''.join(c for c in input() if ord(c) < 256)
while True:
    s = ''.join(c for c in input() if ord(c) < 256)
    if s:
        inpt += "\n" + s
    else:
        break
```

and this works:

```
✔uganda
✔zambia
✔zimbabwe
and none of these…
✕afghanistan
✕armenia
✕azerbaijan

>>> inpt
'uganda\nzambia\nzimbabwe\nand none of these\nafghanistan\narmenia\nazerbaijan'
>>> print(inpt)    
uganda
zambia
zimbabwe
and none of these
afghanistan
armenia
azerbaijan
```

Comment: because you don’t initialise the inpt as an empty string, this is difficult to use in the shell

Comment: @micsthepick I had edited the solution anyway as before it would add a newline to the start of the string but if the current solution still isn't working for you, then you could just actually create a script and run it...

Comment: that is not always a possibility

Answer (score 0):

If you have data stored in your session and can’t just execute a script, then you could just run an input loop to copy in the full input.

code:

```
inp = ""


for line in iter(input, “”):
        inp += line
```

Answer (score 0):

Define it in a script.  File, New, then:

```
#!coding:utf8
s = u'''✔uganda
✔zambia
✔zimbabwe
and none of these…
✕afghanistan
✕armenia
✕azerbaijan'''
print s
```

Save it, then press F5 to run it in the IDLE shell.  Output:

```
✔uganda
✔zambia
✔zimbabwe
and none of these…
✕afghanistan
✕armenia
✕azerbaijan
```

Alternatively, swith to the latest Python.  3.6's Idle works fine:

```
>>> s='''\
✔uganda
✔zambia
✔zimbabwe
and none of these…
✕afghanistan
✕armenia
✕azerbaijan'''
>>> print(s)
✔uganda
✔zambia
✔zimbabwe
and none of these…
✕afghanistan
✕armenia
✕azerbaijan
```